# Publish Over CIFS Plugin in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jcifs

I am using Publish over CIFS Plugin. I have set up the Test Configuration and it gives me success messages. I am using it under Post build step in job as “Send build artifact to a Windows share”.

[Build Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loWRv.png)

[My Job Configuration:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxT6E.png)

[System Configuration:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVJp5.png)

- The test configuration is successful but it always transfer 0 files.
- I have tried to clean remote directory from post build action in that job and it did clean my whole    wwwroot directory.
- That means it is communicating but not able to transfer files. Something I am missing..
- I have one more doubt, source location should be our Jenkins workspace or we can transfer file from any location?
- In my case I am trying to transfer all the files from inetpub\wwwroot\particular project files in a post build step.

Can anyone PLEASE help me? Thanks in advance